# Persist Network when generating IP Range (R IP Tools)

Tags: r, ip, rstudio, cidr

Apologies in advance if this has an obvious answer; I have a vector of IPv4 networks in CIDR notation (e.g. 192.168.100.14/24) and I want to generate the IPs that are in each network, but also to persist the network information, in R Studio.

Using the IP Tools package, I can generate the IPs that are in each network, but I don't know how to carry the CIDR notated network forward into the data set.

Currently I'm just doing this:

```
iprange <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(CIDR_data))
{ 
  iprange <- c(iprange,range_generate(CIDR_data$Network[i]))
}
```

I've tried doing a number of things, mostly using the ip_in_range function in the same package and the match function in the base package, to try to "find" the network for each IP after generating the IPs, but am having no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else finds this useful, I did it in Python 3.6 using the ipaddress module (included in the base package):

```
inactive_ips = []
inactive_networks = []

for i in networks:
    inactive_ips.append(list(ipaddress.ip_network(i).hosts()))
    ## this won't include the host & broadcast IPs!
    inactive_networks.append(str(i))

both = zip(inactive_ips, inactive_networks)
both_values = tuple(both)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my [ipaddress](https://davidchall.github.io/ipaddress/) package, this is fairly simple. If you want the list of addresses to match your Python code, you can use [`hosts()`](https://davidchall.github.io/ipaddress/reference/sequence.html) instead of [`seq()`](https://davidchall.github.io/ipaddress/reference/sequence.html).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ipaddress)

tibble(network = ip_network(c("192.168.100.0/30", "192.168.0.0/31"))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(addresses = list(seq(network))) %>%
  unnest_longer(addresses, values_to = "address")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>            network       address
#>         <ip_netwk>     <ip_addr>
#> 1 192.168.100.0/30 192.168.100.0
#> 2 192.168.100.0/30 192.168.100.1
#> 3 192.168.100.0/30 192.168.100.2
#> 4 192.168.100.0/30 192.168.100.3
#> 5   192.168.0.0/31   192.168.0.0
#> 6   192.168.0.0/31   192.168.0.1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>